# A SASS/Compass sprite mixin with retina sprite-sheet option

Tags: sass, compass

I'm trying to write a mixin using sass/Compass that will make use of available spriting functions for both regular-size images and their @2x/@3x counterparts. This is what I've done so far:

```
// including the three sprite maps   
$icons      : sprite-map("icons/*.png")
$icons2x    : sprite-map("icons@2x/*.png")
$icons3x    : sprite-map("icons@3x/*.png")

// the mixin
=retina-spritebox($name, $map: $icons, $rmap2x: $icons2x, $rmap3x: $icons3x, $display: block, $bg-color: transparent)
     display: #{$display}
     text-indent: -9999px
     overflow: hidden
     background: $bg-color $map sprite-position($map, $name)
     +sprite-dimensions($map, $name)

     @media  only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)
         background: $rmap2x nth(sprite-position($rmap2x, $name), 1)/2 nth(sprite-position($rmap2x, $name), 2)/2
         background-size: image-width(sprite-path($rmap2x))/2 image-height(sprite-path($rmap2x))/2

     @media  only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2.5), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/2), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.5), (min-resolution: 2.5dppx)
         background: $rmap3x nth(sprite-position($rmap3x, $name), 1)/3 nth(sprite-position($rmap3x, $name), 2)/3
         background-size: image-width(sprite-path($rmap3x))/3 image-height(sprite-path($rmap3x))/3
```

Everything works exactly as intended – except the things happening inside those media queries. I'm trying to divide the width of the @2x sprite sheet and the x/y coordinates of its sprite by 2, but there doesn't seem to be any way to ensure that the width of the sprite sheet or the coordinates of the sprites will always be  neatly divisible by 2.

I realise that I could just include the @2x image instead, but that would mitigate the performance gain of using a sprite sheet.

A solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these two (if you are not using `bower` download the files from `src/` folder)

- https://github.com/Gaya/Retina-Sprites-for-Compass (separates the files in two different folders)
- https://github.com/pixelmord/Retina-Sprites-for-Compass (saves 1 request)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at those, but I'm really looking for feedback on the code above, not links to plugins.